# Passing a generic class and using it for GORM and cloning in Groovy

Tags: generics, groovy

I want to pass in a generic class as a parameter in Groovy, and then use that object for GORM operations and cloning, something like:

```
def myFunc(Class<T> c, String id) {
 Object o = c.get(id)
 Object newO = o.clone()
 return newO
}
```

I'm planning on using AutoClone for the classes that get passed into here. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: what do you plan to do with the clone?  do you just want to have an immutable instance or do you plan to write a new object?

Comment: I want to be able to write a new object

Comment: then nullifying your primary key should be enough

Answer (score 0):

One way I came up of doing this is:

```
def myFunc(Class c, String id,) {
 Object obj = c.newInstance() 
 Object old = c.get(id)
 obj = old.clone()
 return obj
}
```

An issue that might come up with this is `MissingPropertyException` if the old object that was retrieved doesn't have values for all the properties.